# Is this x==(int)(float)x always true?

Tags: c, floating-point

`x` is `int`.

I think `x==(int)(float)x` is always true,but the book says it false when `x` is `TMax`.
I've checked it when `x=TMax`,it's still true. The book is wrong?

Comment: What is `IMax`, and what is `TMax`?

Comment: sorry,someone edited.  so why it is true when x is TMax,it has a precision of more than 24 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` has a precision of 24 bits with IEEE-754 floating point formats. As soon as you have more precision in your integer value, you lose precision. Try the same on a system which has 32 bit `int`s and you'll see the difference.

For example, take

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 4000000003U;
    float y = x;
    printf ("%u %.20g %.20g %u\n", x, (float)x, y, (unsigned int)(float)x);
}
```

which will convert this large number to a float. This float is incapable to hold the whole number, so it approximates it.

After converting back to an `int`, you get a different value.

At least, you should get one, but I cannot reproduce this on my sytem here: the program above outputs

```
4000000003 4000000003 4000000000 4000000003
```

while I expected the second number to be equal to the third...

However, if I change the code to 64 bit integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    uint64_t x = 400000000000000003U;
    double y = x;
    printf ("%" PRIu64 " %.20g %.20g %" PRIu64 "\n", x, (double)x, y,
(uint64_t)(double)x);
}
```

it will work as expected: 64 bit are even more than a `double` can hold (this would be 53 bit), and thus it works as wanted.

Comment: I think the results have to do with C 6.3.1.8p2: "The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby."

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right, I forgot the implicit bit.

Comment: @aschepler read the footnote on the paragraph you quote: "The cast and assignment operators are still required to remove extra range and precision.”  Failing to adhere to this requirement is a compiler bug.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) is used, the single precision `float` can represent integers accurately only within 2<sup>24</sup>, but `int` is normally 32-bit in modern computer, the integers outside the range may not be cast back with `(int)(float)x`

If `double` is used instead of `float`, `x == (int)(double)x` is true for all 32-bit integers, because `double` can represent integers within 2<sup>53</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessarily true, because floating point loses precision as you increase the magnitude of your values.

Comment: Converting an integer to `float` *always* gets you an exact integer.  (But if the value is far from zero, it might get you the wrong integer.)

Comment: @aschepler: Converting a very large integer to `float` will produce infinity, not an integer, provided you have large enough integers (e.g., GMP).

Answer (score 0):

tczf, you must be reading the book CSAPP, I think you can have a look at the practice problem 2.49, which is on the page 144. A floating-point format with a n-bit fraction can't represent the integer which is larger than 2^(n+1)-1, because it will lose the precision.

Therefore, IEEE 754 single precision floating-point format has 23-bits fraction, and "int" type has 32 bits, so if the integer is larger than 2^24-1, the float type can't represent it exactly. But double floating-point format can, since it has 52-bit fraction.

Answer (score 0):

@[FatSheep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31960150/8449612) 's answer has an error.

> A floating-point format with a n-bit fraction can't represent the integer which is larger than 2^(n+1)-1, because it will lose the precision.

Not `2^(n+1)-1`, the correct one is `which larger than or equal to 2^(n+1) + 1`.

`n + 1` means normalized values have implied leading 1, and significand equals `M = 1 + f`, f represents fraction.
The code will help you.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main(){
    for(int i =0; i < INT_MAX; i++){
        int x = i;
        int y = (int)(float)x;//when x >= 2^(n + 1) + 1, x != y
        if(x != y){
            printf("%d,%d\n",x,y);
            break;
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```